# Generate RTF table rows from PHP loop

Tags: php, document, rtf, dynamically-generated

I am trying to generate RTF document. I have a RTF template that has first row of Table (headings). The rest of the rows are generated from PHP dynamically. I viewed source of RTF document and copied the code for the specific row, I replaced the text with some variable type of names:

```
%%a%% - means that in my PHP code, it looks for %%a%% and replaces with some text
```

The script works, PHP side everything works, it generates replaces the variables. But i get an error as soon as i try to open the RTF document generated:

> A table in this document has become corrupted.

My RTF code to generate inside PHP loop is this:

```
\trowd \irow1\irowband1\ts18\trgaph108\trleft-813\trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrh\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrv\brdrs\brdrw10 
\trftsWidth3\trwWidth10795\trftsWidthB3\trftsWidthA3\trpaddl108\trpaddr108\trpaddfl3\trpaddft3\trpaddfb3\trpaddfr3\tbllkhdrrows\tbllklastrow\tbllkhdrcols\tbllklastcol \clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrr
\brdrs\brdrw10 \cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1728\clshdrawnil \cellx915\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1620\clshdrawnil \cellx2535\clvertalt\clbrdrt
\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1260\clshdrawnil \cellx3795\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 
\cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1440\clshdrawnil \cellx5235\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1440\clshdrawnil \cellx6675\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 
\clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1440\clshdrawnil \cellx8115\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 
\cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1867\clshdrawnil \cellx9982\row }\pard\plain \qj \li0\ri0\sl360\slmult1\widctlpar\intbl\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\pararsid9917761\yts18 \fs24\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 {
\f37\fs20\insrsid5056707 %%a%%}{\f37\fs20\ul\cf6\insrsid5335176\charrsid15606364 \cell }{\f37\fs20\insrsid5056707 %%b%%}{\f37\fs20\ul\cf6\insrsid5335176\charrsid15606364 \cell }{\f37\fs20\insrsid5056707 %%c%%}{
\f37\fs20\ul\cf6\insrsid5335176\charrsid15606364 \cell }{\f37\fs20\insrsid5056707 %%d%%}{\f37\fs20\ul\cf6\insrsid5335176\charrsid15606364 \cell }{\f37\fs20\insrsid5056707 %%e%%}{\f37\fs20\ul\cf6\insrsid5335176\charrsid15606364 \cell }{
\f37\fs20\insrsid5056707 %%f%%}{\f37\fs20\ul\cf6\insrsid5335176\charrsid15606364 \cell }{\f37\fs20\insrsid5056707 %%g%%}{\f37\fs20\ul\cf6\insrsid5335176\charrsid15606364 \cell }\pard\plain 
\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\intbl\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0 \fs24\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 {\b\f37\fs28\ul\cf6\insrsid5335176
```

If anyone knows RTF syntax, do I have a syntax mistake somewhere? Please help.

Comment: does it really have to be RTF?

Comment: yes or .doc but i dont know how togenerate .doc documents. The code was given to me that generates RTF thats why im struggling with the syntax of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your  `RTF` simply is not valid missing headers , font definition,  unclosed `}` etc.  ..

Try

```
$template = "test/hey_main.rtf";
$newfile = "test/hey_x.rtf";

$rtf = file_get_contents($template);

$replace = array("%%no%%"=>1,"%%name%%"=>"Giorgi","%%Value%%"=>"Sample RTF");
$rtf = str_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $rtf);

file_put_contents($newfile, $rtf)
```

`hey_main.rtf` RTF Example

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033\deflangfe1033{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fprq2\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f1\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\trowd\trgaph108\trleft-108\trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \trpaddl108\trpaddr108\trpaddfl3\trpaddfr3
\clbrdrl\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrt\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrw10\brdrs \cellx3084\clbrdrl\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrt\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrw10\brdrs \cellx6276\clbrdrl\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrt\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrw10\brdrs \cellx9468\pard\intbl\b\f1\fs22 No\b0\cell\b Name\b0\cell\b Value\b0\cell\row\trowd\trgaph108\trleft-108\trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \trpaddl108\trpaddr108\trpaddfl3\trpaddfr3
\clbrdrl\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrt\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrw10\brdrs \cellx3084\clbrdrl\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrt\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrw10\brdrs \cellx6276\clbrdrl\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrt\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrw10\brdrs \cellx9468\pard\intbl %%no%%\cell %%name%%\cell %%Value%%\cell\row\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\par
}
```

- [Download hey_main.rtf](http://bayfiles.com/file/pa9x/aypfrw/hey_main.rtf)
- [Download hey_x.rtf](http://bayfiles.com/file/paa3/MJCcMS/hey_x.rtf)

Comment: its missing } tag because its generated inside a loop, i need table rows, i know how to create simple text and replace variables but i need dynamic table rows to be generated with data

Comment: What are you using to generate your RTF ???? can use use this http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/25616.html ... ??/